# how to check data model values changed angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an online Web form using angular.js.  When the user edits the information and clicks back it loses the unsaved data. How can I check whether the data model values have changed and warn the user that they have unsaved information that needs to be saved before navigating away?

I have forked this example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZ8pbPSIYlE0dkSBFGBs?p=preview)

```
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
```

Comment: Have you made any try with the code ?

Comment: yes I used the validation but that is not enough

Comment: @user3277743 why validation is not enough?

Comment: I will create sample plunker wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this directive to warn unsaved data when user leaves from the page inject this directive and change the messages

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        var initial = {text: 'initial value'};
        $scope.mySample = angular.copy(initial);
    }

    angular.module("myApp", []).directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
        return {
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                        return "The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                    }
                }
                $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                    if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                        if(!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" confirm-on-exit>
      Text: <input name="input" ng-model="mySample.text">
        <p>mySample = {{mySample.text}}</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edited and posted entire code.My Plunker didnt works. Please use this code and check. it will work